# cryptsetup luksAddKey pipe

Tags: bash, luks

I hope this is the correct place to make this question. Anyway...
I was trying to create a script to add a passphrase by piping it to the command luksAddKey with a script. When i try to pipe the "old" passphrase i get this error:

```
No key available with this passphrase.
```

And the code i run in the terminal is the following:

```
sudo ./change_key_script oldPassphrase newPassphrase
```

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

oldPassword=$1
newPassword=$2

rootdevice=`sudo blkid | grep disk-uuid | awk '/:/ { print $1}' | sed 's/\(.*\)./\1/'`

## enabled key
enabledkey=`sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdaX | grep ': ENABLED' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs | sed 's/\(.*\)./\1/'`

(echo -ne $oldPassword; echo -ne $newPassword; echo -ne $newPassword) | cryptsetup luksAddKey $rootdevice
```

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I forgot to say that this script is running with root privileges written in sudoers file

Comment: also asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17428152/7552

Comment: deleted on stackoverflow

Comment: use expect - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/

Comment: For all readers following this approach, please note this is rather insecure. All arguments to a command (passwords here!) can be read by any user on the system! (try `ps -au`) This will make your passwords visible plaintext by others for the moment you're running this script.

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved by changing the echo

```
echo -e $oldPassword\n$newPassword\n$newPassword | sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey $rootdevice
```

Comment: Better written as `printf '%s\n' "$oldPassword" "$newPassword" "$newPassword"` just in case you have backslashes or spaces or even funnier symbols in your password. And it's less ugly too (and better quoted).

Comment: No there's a check for the password to be only alphanumeric but thanks for the advice

Comment: I had to wrap $oldPassword\n$newPassword\n$newPassword in " " otherwise the new lines weren't expressed.